# Run j2me jar file

Tags: java-me, opera, nokia

I have downloaded Opera mini from http://www.opera.com/mini/download/nokia/nokia_6600/

I downloaded both the jad and jar files,
opera-mini-4.2.13918-advanced-en.jad
opera-mini-4.2.13918-advanced-en.jar
and copied them to the bin directory of Sun java wireless toolkit,
[C:\j2me emulator\emulator\bin]

For running the file i'm using following command

```
emulator -Xdevice:DefaultColorPhone -Xdescriptor:opera-mini-4.2.13918-advanced-en.jad -Dcom.sun.midp.io.http.proxy=10.0.0.10:9401
```

My internet connection is through proxy server, whenever i start the application it say "failed to connect to internet" help me
I'm using Sun_Java_TM__Wireless_Toolkit_2_5_1_for_CLDC

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try your setup from a computer that is not behind a proxy server. You will then (hopefully) know whether it is the proxy server that causes your problems or not.